eclipse working in /home ubuntu but not executing on other drive
My OS is UBUNTU. I installed eclipse at /home/eclipse and its working fine but when I move or fresh install it to another drive /media/linux/WINSOFT/Program Files/Java/eclipse then its not executing/openig with following error:
eclipse error
Error Message is:
Could Not Display "eclipse"
There is no app installed for "Executable" files.
Do you want to search for an app to open this file?
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I wan to run eclilpse from /media/linux/WINSOFT/Program Files/Java/eclipse  but it throws error: Could Not Display "eclipse" There is no app installed for "Executable" files. Do you want to search for an app to open this file?

sounds like you are trying to run the Windows version of Eclipse or java on Linux.

No, I am using linux version of Eclipse. Its executing from /home/eclipse but not executing from say /media/linux/WINSOFT/Java/. I also set its path but in vain. When I copy past same folder in /home then it executing fine

I am using eclipse-jee-2024-09-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Sounds like the eclipse file may not have execute permission
